# Using the year extracted from a date field as a groupby expression in Pands

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract the year from a date in a DataFrame, and use this as the group by axis.

```
maa_lu_grouped_year = df_all_lu.groupby(df_all_lu["LU_APPROVED_DT"].dt.year)
```

I am doing this by guesswork as I know you can pass a function such as "len" into the groupby expression, but wasn't sure how to apply a function on a single column.

Now this seems to work, I just don't know why it is working!!

Comment: `df_all_lu.groupby(df_all_lu["LU_APPROVED_DT"].dt.year)['col_name'].apply(func)`?

Comment: I don't understand. What are you asking for? How to apply a function to a pd.DataFrame.groupby  or why your group by  year works? @smackenzie

Comment: I have a date field in my DataFrame (LU_APPROVED_DT).  I want to extract the year from that date, and group my frame by that year.  Is my syntax correct, as I can't find any examples to do this online?

Comment: @QuangHoang Not sure I understand, LU_APPROVED_DT is my col_name I am trying to get the year from?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What are you asking for?:  if the syntax is correct? Why this groupby works? ...? @smackenzie

Comment: @MrNobody33 why does it work

Comment: why wouldn't it work? That is how [groupby works](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/), so you gave the column of years, something like `[2012, 2012, 2015 2015, 2015]` I guess and the it groups the dataframe based on that column. @smackenzie